# Error 404 when trying to create a pretty url using .htaccess in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to create a pretty rule in php using .htaccess.

something like `localhost/search/name` instead of using the normal PHP way like `search?q=name`. But am stuck in implementing it because all my page are now returning  `error 404` and I don't know why.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^localhost/?$ search.php?name=$1 [QSA]`
```

Here is my search.php file:

```
<?php 
    echo $_GET['name']; 
?>
```

So when I visit something like `localhost/search/myname` it returns `error 404`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to first also include the /search/ as part of the rewrite rule and then i would also suggest adding in the 'L' flag after QSA so the rule is the last rule processed when called.

You then want to capture the name from the url and pass this through as a get param to the view.

I've also ommitted localhost from the URL as you don't need to target this.

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: apologies, i've removed the offending space